# How can I get favicons to appear in tabs in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, favicon

I upgraded to Firefox 4 and now favicons don't show in my tabs.

How to I get them to show? They exist in the bookmarks.

Comment: Just for understanding: Do you see the favicons in your bookmarks but not in the tab? Or do you don´t see any favicons at all?

Comment: on my XP box, after the upgrade I don't see them either place.  On W7 box they are fine.

Comment: I have so many tabs open all I can see are the favicons.  I can imagine how annoying it would be to lose those!  What "skin" are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I could be caused either by Greasemonkey or a favicon picker extension.

When I disabled them, the problem disappeared. It worked afterwards also when I re-enabled them.

Comment: I had a same problem.Thanks @Ludoja, after uninstalling Favicon Picker extension everything goes back to normal :)

Answer (score 1):

To those who have made suggestions to resolve my problem:
I solved my problem, mostly, by brute force.  I removed FF4 from my XP machine. I had to use Revo to remove all traces including all bookmarks, etc..  Then I reinstalled FF4.  After I reinstalled I sync'd the new install with what was on my W7 machine.  This refreshed my bookmarks but not the favicons. I then used the Check Places add-on to get the favicons on my bookmarks, when a favicon existed on the site.  Victory!

There are obviously sites that do not provide favicons but I can create favicons for those.  I have at least one site the does not provide a favicon that I have not figured out.  It is a financial institution and the favicon I create shows in the bookmark and will show momentarily in the tab when I visit the site but it then vanishes and I cannot get it to stay in the tab, weird.

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The most common (and normal) scenario that assumes nothing else has fundamentally gone wrong with your Firefox installation is to simply clear your cache and visit the site. It should immediately load up the favicon at that point.

If that does not remedy things, you can try to make sure that in your about:config settings, the "browser.chrome.favicons" preference is set to "true".

Comment: I've cleared the cache.  I've verified the about:config settings and "browser.chrome.favicons" preference is set to "true".  Guess I don't understand what difference that makes for FF though.  Thanks but I'm still stumped.

Comment: If the usage of the term "Chrome" in there caused confusion, then hopefully [this link](http://www.rietta.com/firefox/Tutorial/conf.html#chrome) will clarify that. It's not meant to be confused with Google's Chrome. Otherwise, it's kind of weird that it's not working for you. If I think of something else I'll mention it.

Comment: Thx xtremesniper, that helps but the terminology gets confusing with the use of the word chrome.  I'm frustrated with favicons but I find them necessary, especially when using app tabs.

Answer (score 0):

Given how deep the changes go in Firefox 4, you may want to just create a fresh profile and copy over your stuff.

For me, the upgrade brought stuff like the address bar not changing when I changed tabs and making a fresh profile only took me maybe an hour as opposed to a day or more.

Here's a summary of the ways I found to make it as painless as possible:

- Use the [Add-on Collector extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/pages/collector) to sync your installed addons via a private collection.
- If you use Greasemonkey, with Firefox not running...

  - Copy the `gm_scripts` folder from the old profile to the new one.
  - Open `prefs.js` in the old and new profiles and copy the block of `greasemonkey.scriptvals.` lines over.
- If you use Stylish, with Firefox not running, copy `stylish.sqlite` from the old profile to the new one.
- If you use NoScript or SiteLauncher, use their Import/Export buttons to copy your settings over.
- Export all bookmarks with "Import and Backup" button in the Bookmarks editor window.

  - This also covered search engines for me since putting a `%s` placeholder in a bookmark's URL and setting a keyword gives a more Polished Omnibar-style experience than setting a keyword on search engines installed via the search box.

...and then, with the export/import process having done some ad-hoc sanitization on your bookmarks, sign up for Firefox Sync so your bookmarks, saved passwords, history, open tabs, and a safe subset of your preferences won't have to be manually copied over the next time. (I could be wrong, but I think AdBlock Plus also supports Sync for its settings. NoScript can be synced [via Bookmarks Sync](http://hackademix.net/2009/05/13/synchronizing-noscript-configuration-using-weave-or-xmarks/).)